# iOS Swift: Delete parse array item referenced by index

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have data stored in parse column with following column keys

phone = ["iPhone", "Galaxy S6", "Nexus"]

quantity = [20, 30, 20]

boolV = [[true, false], [true, false], [false,true]]

I am presenting this date in tableView format to the user and want to give him the option to delete these items.

At present I am following this:
Inside tableView commitEditingStyle function

```
// find the index value of user selected cell
var indexValue = find(phone, "iPhone") // 0
// Using this, I can delete the array elements from phone like this
quantity.removeAtIndex(indexValue!)
boolV.removeAtIndex(indexValue!)
```

To delete from parse I using the following:

```
object.removeObject("iPhone", forKey: "phone") // This works fine
object.removeObject("self.quantity[indexValue]", forKey: "quantity") // But this deletes both "20" quantity from the table
object.removeObject("self.boolV[indexValue]", forKey: "boolV") // again it deleted both "[true, false]" values form the array.
```

I am sure I am missing something here. I just want to delete array item pointed by the indexValue. How can I do that in Parse? Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This really seems like you should use a different data model with 2 classes and a relationship rather than 1 class and a set of array attributes. Then, to do the deletion you remove an item from the relationship and delete it from the data store.

The way you have it at the moment you can't delete individual items from the array, you need to take the array, edit it and then store the full new updated array.

Comment: Thank you. I am way too far to change the data model. Also, I am new to programming so making such a big change would be a problem. Can you please help me understand the way in which I can delete a particular item in a parse array using index? Like delete item contained in an array with a specific index value? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you should delete in the background like this: objects is your tableView connected array

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            let objectToDelete = objects?[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
            objectToDelete.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (success) {
                    // Force a reload of the table - fetching fresh data from Parse platform
                    self.loadObjects()
                } else {
                    // There was a problem, check error.description
                }
            }
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Ersil Thank you. I am already using delete in background. I didn't show this in this post as the whole idea is to understand how to delete an item using index value from Parse. But thanks you very much for suggestion. Do you know how to delete item from Parse array using index value?

Comment: as you see let objectToDelete = objects?[indexPath.row] as! PFObject but before that you should addObjects with parse results[which are supposed to delete], to your MutableArray called "objects" in this example